# Visual Studio 2010's Build Command: It does nothing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, xna

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express RTM with Windows Phone Developer Tools April CTP Refresh and when I run any Build option, nothing happens. I've deleted the contents of the build output folders and that doesn't do anything. I can't even run the project, because it complains the executable is missing (XNA Game for Windows project). I've tried the project on another computer and it builds just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a reinstall?

Comment: Or, a repair of the installation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how this happens, but here's how I fixed it:

1. Open Build -> Configuration Manager
2. In the "Platform" column, choose x86 instead of Any CPU
3. Click close

These exact steps may not work for you, but I've found that if you play around in the Configuration Manager window it will usually resolve this problem.

Comment: Also, in my Output window I saw this:
`Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped`

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't work with current versions of XNA Studio. You'll could wait until XNA Studio 4 comes out (apparently due this month).

To solve your issue, use Visual Studio 2008 or use the workaround at [this link](http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2010/02/visual-studio-2010-xna-and-you/) to continue using VS2010 and XNA.